# How can I make SQL search ignore language-specific special characters?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have an sql table which contains data with special characters for my language (Slovak), for example:

```
 id | name
 1    František
 2    Ján
 3    Júlia
```

Now, I need to run a search on this table (SELECT ... %string%), where while searching for `julia` it should match `Júlia`, or even generally, `ju` should find `Júlia`.

My database already is case insensitive, I just need to make it ignore those special characters.

How would I do this?

Comment: default collation does it. [See here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3635a/2)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
select * from t
where name like 'Julia' collate utf8_unicode_ci
```

You can use a different collation in your selects. 
You can see what collations your installation supports by

```
SELECT COLLATION_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLLATIONS
```

[SQLFiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3635a/8)
[MySQL Collations](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/charset-charsets.html)